# Selenium Automation - How to create a user in Auth0 tenant for which we can bypass the SSO login

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, ui-automation, auth0, login-automation

We have recently move our login application from AWS cognito to Auth0. In cognito we have an option to create a user directly in user pool and we were able to bypass the SSO login for our test automation.

However with Auth0, we have created a tenant. I am able to create a user inside it but not able to figure out how to disable MFA for the same and set a password.

Any idea or suggestion how to accomplish this for our automation. If there are any other way to automate the login without SSO that would be great help as well.
We are using Selenium with Python for automation.

Have tried to create a user in Auth0, however after that couldn't able to proceed.